# import csv-table into R and got multiple errors

Tags: r, csv, import, error-handling

As you can see I would like to read a csv-table into my data-pool. The table has multiple columns but when i simply try following code:

```
reviews <- read.table("Sz-Iraki2.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

i get the error: **Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 22 elements**

When i Add **header=True i get the error: more columns than column names**. Seems like a basic problem but i can´t find the answer :(strong text

but should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPmrV.png)

Data looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfBOT.png)

Comment: You may need to define the field separator explicitly. If that field separator also occurs in unquoted fields, this can lead to the error you see.

Comment: If it's a csv file maybe you should try `read.csv`. If the error still occurs try using argument `fill = TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a separator otherwise R fail to read data properly. Suppose your data structure is the following:

```
structure(list(month = 2:5, titles_tmp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "some text", class = "factor"), info_tmp = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "More text", class = "factor"), unlist.text = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "http://somelink.com", class = "factor")), .Names = c("month", 
"titles_tmp", "info_tmp", "unlist.text"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

That means you separate each columns with single tab. Meaning you need to use `sep = " "` as a data separator. Provided your data file name is "df.csv" the following should import your data nicely:

```
df = read.csv("Sz-Iraki2.csv", sep= " ", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, but that did not help. i added two screenshots of my interface, that might clearify my problem

Comment: Try different separators e.g. sep = "\t". Also would be great to see actual data snipet you are trying to import.

Comment: Ok ty, i added the data snipet

Comment: You added an image that is not very convenient, just copy your data to clipboard and paste it or use dput(). Suppose your data is in object df then use dput(head(df, 5)) to show the snippet.

Comment: I edited posted answer. You may try:  df = read.csv("Sz-Iraki2.csv", sep= " ", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

Answer (score 0):

I like to use:

```
require(readr)

read_csv("myData.csv")
```

Seems more appropriate, if your file type is csv.

Also comes with some useful options like defining 'coltype' on import.